# Sql Server 2005 Swap ID Numbers

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table that has two columns "name" and "ID". where ID is not null.

I am trying to create a stored prcedure to swap the IDs around for two names when imputed here is what i have so far.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.procName 
    @OldName NVARCHAR(128), 
    @NewName NVARCHAR(128)
AS

DECLARE @NewId0 INT,
    @NewId1 INT,
    @OldId0 INT, 
    @OldId1 INT, 
    @Number INT


SELECT @NewId0 = ID FROM Table1 WHERE [Name] = @NewName
SELECT @NewId1 = ID FROM Table1 WHERE [Name] = @NewName
SELECT @OldId0 = ID FROM Table1 WHERE [Name] = @OldName
SELECT @OldId1 = ID FROM Table1 WHERE [Name] = @OldName
SELECT @Number = 0 

UPDATE Table1 SET ID = @Number WHERE ID = @NewId0 
UPDATE Table1 SET ID = @NewId1 WHERE ID = @OldId0 
UPDATE Table1 SET ID = @OldID1 WHERE ID = @NewID0 


Go
```

All I get is the first name to have the value 0.

I think my logic is correct but it doesn't seem to be working is there something that I am missing?

Comment: If your table has only two columns, why not just swap Name columns then?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like

```
UPDATE  Table1
SET     ID =    CASE 
                    WHEN ID = @NewId 
                        THEN @OldId
                    ELSE @NewId
                END
WHERE   ID IN (@NewId, @OldId)
```

Here is a full example

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Name VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1,'A'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2,'B'

DECLARE @NewName VARCHAR(20),
        @OldName VARCHAR(20)

SELECT  @NewName = 'A',
        @OldName = 'B'

DECLARE @NewId INT, 
    @OldId INT


SELECT @NewId = ID FROM @Table WHERE [Name] = @NewName 
SELECT @OldId = ID FROM @Table WHERE [Name] = @OldName  

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table

UPDATE  @Table
SET     ID =    CASE 
                    WHEN ID = @NewId 
                        THEN @OldId
                    ELSE @NewId
                END
WHERE   ID IN (@NewId, @OldId)

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table
```

Answer (score 0):

This script works if the ID is not a primary Key

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.procName 
                              @OldName NVARCHAR(128), 
                              @NewName NVARCHAR(128)
As
DECLARE @NewId INT,
        @OldId INT

SELECT @NewId = ID FROM Table1 WHERE [Name] = @NewName
SELECT @OldId = ID FROM Table1 WHERE [Name] = @OldName

UPDATE  Table1 
SET     ID =    CASE
                WHEN ID = @NewId
                THEN @OldId 
                ELSE @NewId 
                END 
WHERE   ID IN (@NewId, @OldId)

SELECT  * 
FROM    Table1
go

Answer (score 0):

Your current code fails because:

- You Look for @NewId0, and set it to @Number (which is 0)
- You then look for @OldId0, and set it to @NewId1
- You then look for @NewId0 again... but two lines back, you set it to 0, so it's not in the table any more

I like @astander's solution (upvoted), saved me writing it out myself.

BUT... your comment, "...ID is a Primary Key", raises all kinds of red flags. You really, *really* don't want to change primary key values [*insert long discussion from past classes about primary keys and relational integrity here*]. Figure out why you think you need to do it, and then figure out another way to implement that business requirement, such as:

- Don't change the IDs, change everything else (name, description, cost, whatever)
- Create completely new entries and drop (or mark as completed, discareded, or junk) the old ones
- Implement some clever logic based on the underlying business requirements.

Answer (score 0):

under stand the concerns with changing PKs but it has to be done as it would take too long to change all the other stuff. That said I have come up with an answer. This is only the first part of a long script so again its not perfect:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ID @OldName NVARCHAR(128), 
                        @NewName NVARCHAR(128)

AS
DECLARE @NewId INT,
        @OldId INT

CREATE TABLE TmpTable (ID INT,Name NVARCHAR(128)) 

INSERT INTO TmpTable (Name,ID) 
VALUES (@NewName,(SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE [Name] = @NewName));

INSERT INTO TmpTable (Name,ID)
VALUES(@OldName,(SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE [Name] = @OldName))

UPDATE Table1 SET ID = 11 WHERE [NAME]  = @NewName
UPDATE Table1 SET ID = 10 WHERE [NAME]  = @OldName

UPDATE Table1 SET ID = (SELECT ID FROM TmpTable where Name = @NewName)WHERE [Name] = @OldName
UPDATE Table1 SET ID = (SELECT ID FROM TmpTable where Name = @OldName) WHERE [Name] = @NewName

DROP TABLE TmpTable
go
```

"11" and "10" were selected as they are not in the table my next mission will be to query table1 and for a random number that dosent exist then use that number to temprary repplace the ID before updating the new ones.

Thanks